# How to apply preferences to a d3.tree node

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have adapted a code from

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550

to make a nice figure for the tidy arrangement of layered nodes. Assume I have a similar flare.csv file as on the webpage. The code right now assigns color based on whether a node is on an internal circle (which means the node has two links) or on an outer circle.

What I want instead is to assign a specific color (let's say blue) to the point located in the center (the parent node) whose name is flare. Also I want to assign a specific color(let's say red) to all outer-circle nodes (those have only one connection) which name is "sub".

All other nodes could be only black.

How can I implement what I want in the HTML code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for parents and children when styling the circles:

```
node.append("circle")
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return !d.parent ? "blue" : d.children ? "red" : "black";
    })
    .attr("r", 2.5);
```

Here is your update bl.ocks: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/696c1201ed63715753e76e480db343f0

EDIT: colouring only your specified node:

```
.style("fill", function(d){
    return !d.parent ? "blue" : d.data.id === "flare.vis.data" ? "red" : "black";
})
```

Here is the bl.ocks: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/b55bc1e54414b4bbbfebee93ac6912a4

Comment: Dear Gerardo, Very grateful for your explanation. This certainly solves my problem with the main parent node "flare" as it is blue now. But for the children nodes, seemingly what you did only changes the color of all children nodes which are also parent (have two links) that is d.children. The second part is not what I wanted. What I need is actually to change the color of a specific children node which NAME is "Data", for instance, and is located on an outer circle, that is it has only one link. I am so thankful if you may kindly assist me accomplish my goal. Thanks.

Comment: My most sincere apologies if my question sounds very naive. I am new to javascript. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: In that case, just change the tertiary operator in my answer to the condition you want. Besides that, it's a good idea posting **your** code.

Comment: I did this but all nodes except the !d.parent node turn black. I just don't know how I may do so. Sorry. 


node.append("circle")
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return !d.parent ? "blue" : d.Data ? "red" : "black";
    })
    .attr("r", 2.5);

Comment: There is no name for any node in that data structure. I advise you to specify clearly what you want.

Comment: Kindly locate the node flare.vis.data.Data in the diagram you just created. I want the node corresponding to this be red. You may find this data structure in the flare.csv file as well. This is what I meant by saying the node name

Comment: Check the edit. I ended up choosing the wrong node, just change the string to `flare.vis.data.Data`.