# How to select all d.data.id ends in a specified word in a d3.tree code?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

After receiving an answer in [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44092303/how-to-apply-preferences-to-a-d3-tree-node), I could modify a d3.tree code in a desired way.

Kindly, imagine I have the following flare.csv file

```
A
A.A
A.A.B
A.A.C
A.B
A.B.C
A.C
A.C.D
A.D
A.D.A
A.D.B
A.D.D
A.E
A.E.A
A.E.B
```

However, I encountered another question. To assign color to some specific nodes,I was advised the answerer to add

```
.style("fill", function(d){
   return !d.parent ? "blue" : d.data.id === "A.D.B" ? "red" : 
"black";
})
```

This basically change the color of the parent node to blue and that of the "A.D.B" to red.

Now as you may see I have several d.data.id's end in the letter"B". For instance, "A.D.B", "A.E.B", and "A.A.B". what is the simplest way in a html javascript code to do the same action for all of these nodes, that is, change their color to red, THAT IS, ALL IDS END IN LETTER"B".

In linux and Matlab, one is able to use "*B" to accomplish this goal. Since I'm new with javascript I need your help to figure this out.
Please note that, I am dealing with a large set of d.data.id so that specifying all of them in the code is very time consuming. Thus, I am looking for a handy way.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to change just the colours of the `data` nodes, or their children as well?

Comment: I will edit the question my friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to colour red the nodes that end with `data`, just split the string:

```
var array = d.data.id.split(".");
```

And check for the last element. In the case of your hypothetical CSV:

```
return !d.parent ? "blue" : array[array.length-1] === "B" ? "red" : "black";
```

This will colour red any ID ending in `B`.

And in the case of the real bl.ocks (regarding your pre-edit question):

```
.style("fill", function(d){
    var array = d.data.id.split(".");
    return !d.parent ? "blue" : array[array.length-1] === "data" ? "red" : "black";
})
```

Here is the updated bl.ocks: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/bb3ff95151d3252597d52c917489dda2

Comment: Dear Gerardo,I am wondering if you may kindly be willing to assist me with my new question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44168459/how-to-change-the-color-of-all-links-with-determined-initial-and-final-d-data-id?noredirect=1#comment75353642_44168459]

Answer (score 0):

**Not the best answer, but alternatively you could...**

Add logical operators to the ternary conditions to include other indices.

```
.style("fill", function(d){
   return !d.parent ? "blue" : (d.data.id === "A.D.B" || d.data.id === "A.D.D") ? "red" : 
"black";
})
```