# How to change the color of all links with determined initial and final d.data.id in a d3.tree tidy code?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

So far I have received great helps and answers regarding [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44093615/how-to-select-all-d-data-id-ends-in-a-specified-word-in-a-d3-tree-code)  on d3.tree code.

I have two more questions and hope someone kindly assist me.

Assume I have the same flare.csv file as the one in my previous question (with small modifications), that is,

```
A
A.A
A.A.B
A.A.C
A.B
A.B.C
A.C
A.C.D
A.D
A.D.A
A.D.B
A.D.D
A.E
A.E.A
A.E.B
A.F
A.H
```

How can I modify the code such that all links between A and B (that is A is the parent and B is the child) become yellow, for instance? Note that I don't want any change in cases where B is the parent and A is the child.

My other question which is not of my main interest right now, is if it is possible to change the code such that all outer children appear on the outer circle? In other words and in context of my flare.csv, I want

```
 A.F
 A.H
 A.A.B
 A.A.C
 A.B.C
 A.C.D
 A.D.A
 A.D.B
 A.D.D
 A.E.A
 A.E.B
```

all appear in the same layer. Is it possible?

Thank you so much.

Comment: For the second part of your question, if you want each terminal leaf/child node to be at the same level, regardless of hierarchy, you could try a d3.cluster layout. See the differences here: https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/c7ae41a98b8cbb38f1febf13deb9d294

Comment: Oh I see. I could successfully use the concept. Thank you so much. I am wondering if one can assist me with the first part of my question.